# Universal basis for graph analog of Boolean circuits?

Tags: graph-theory, topos-theory

The NAND gate is universal for Boolean circuits. That means that any function $2^n \to 2$ can be built out of NAND gates.

Let $\Omega$ be the subgraph classifier, i.e., the graph with two vertices $t$, $f$ and five edges $\mbox{in}\colon t\to t$, $\mbox{out}_1\colon t\to t$, $\mbox{out}_2\colon t\to f$, $\mbox{out}_3\colon f\to t$, $\mbox{out}_4\colon f\to f$. There's obviously a finite set of operations that covers all graph homomorphisms from $\Omega^n \to \Omega$, because the set of all operations of that form is finite. But how small can that set be?

Comment: Worth pointing out: an admittedly less systematic synonym for 'NAND", which Wikipedia has decided to be the title of the relevant article, is [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke). Sheffer  seems to have been the first to publish the fact that there is a single binary logical connective which is 'functionally complete'(=a synonym for 'is universal for Boolean circuits'). Bertrand Russell is said to have thought this discovery important, and Russell and Whitehead even changed to this connective when preparing the second, 1927 edition of 'Principia Mathematica'.

Comment: I'm a little confused about whether you want an answer for all $n$ simultaneously or not. If so, it's not clear to me that a counting argument establishes that there must be finitely many generators, although there probably are. (I use "generators" in the sense of generating a Lawvere theory, which is the relevant sense for discussing universal logic gates.)

Comment: I'd be satisfied with a formula parametric in $n$, but surprised if there's not just a set of binary operations that's universal / "functionally complete".

Comment: My comment containing "Russell and Whitehead even changed to this connective", which I'll leave since it still seems relevant upvoted, was accidentally *misleading*. (The reason why it happened was that I believed a non-false-but-very-misleading statement in the largest free encyclopedia on the web.) I correct the comment here, even though this results in a lengthy comment, and very much hope that neither the opening poster nor the moderators will disapprove of that. Now the correction: Reading Kripke, I stumbled upon a passage saying that *Russell and Whitehead did **not change** to* [...]

Comment: [...] *to the Sheffer stroke in the 2nd edition of Principia Mathematica*. The truth is that Wikipedia is *right* in saying that R&W *used* the Sheffer stroke in Principia, *but* the Wikipedia formulation is misleading in that 'used' sounds as if they had used it *throughout*, which is false. The truth is (I now carefully (0) read what Kripke had to say about this, (1) read the introduction in a 1963 edition of the 2nd edition of Principia Mathematica) that *Russell and Whitehead used the Sheffer stroke only in the introduction to the 2nd edition, and in Appendix A and C of op. cit., but [...]

Comment: [...] *not in the main text of the 2nd edition of Principia Mathematica*. In [S. Kripke: Collected Papers Volume 1 Oxford University Press 2011] in the Ch. "Russell's Notion of Scope", p. 249, one reads "[...] Russell does not say [...] that this [i.e. the Sheffer stroke] is the most important work done in mathematical logic since the first definition of *Principia*. [...] Russell is talking about *the ways the book should be rewritten if he had the time*, [emphasis added] [...] 'the most definite improvement' means the improvement least open to controversy or doubt. It shows [...]

Comment: [...] that propositional logic needs only a single primitive, and moreover Nicod has shown that you can get by with only one axiom for propositional logic that way." I conclude this small correction by citing the first setence of the "Introduction to the Second Edition" of Principia Mathematica: "In preparing this new edition of *Principia Mathematica*, the authors have thought it best to leave the text unchanged, except as regards misprints and minor errors, even where they are aware of improvements."

Comment: This makes it unambiguously clear that in the main body of the text, the Sheffer's discovery was not implemented. Rusell and Whitehead then say their main reason for not making substantial changes is [my interpretation] a technological one: changing the internal references was too much work. This is plausible, since at the time there wasn't any automation helping the internal referencing, and Principia Mathematica has many internal references.